# Makefile is not working

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to get my makefile working, but it is giving me some errors and I can't get it to work.

```
 OBJS = Kmeans.o cluster.o data.o 
    CC = g++
    DEBUG = -g
    CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
    LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)

    clustering : $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o clustering

    Kmeans.o : Kmeans.h Kmeans.cpp cluster.h data.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) Kmeans.cpp

cluster.o : cluster.h cluster.cpp data.h 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) cluster.cpp

data.o : data.h data.cpp 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) data.cpp

clean:
    \rm *.o *~ clustering
```

And the files are:

```
clustering.cpp -> #include "Kmeans.h"
Kmeans.cpp     -> #include "Kmeans.h"
Kmeans.h       -> #include "cluster.h"
cluster.cpp    -> #include "cluster.h"
cluster.h      -> #include "data.h"
data.cpp       -> #include "data.h"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:
Sorry, I forgot to include the errors:

```
Kmeans.o: In function `Kmeans::read(char*)':
Kmeans.cpp:(.text+0x53c): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
cluster.o: In function `Cluster::Cluster(int, int, int)':
cluster.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
cluster.cpp:(.text+0x80): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
cluster.o: In function `Cluster::Cluster()':
cluster.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
cluster.cpp:(.text+0x110): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
cluster.o: In function `Cluster::setData(int, int, int)':
cluster.cpp:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `Data::~Data()'
collect2: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1
make: *** [clustering] Error 1
```

Thanks!

I compile each file and the problem is in the last line:

```
g++    -c -o clustering.o clustering.cpp
g++    -c -o data.o data.cpp
g++    -c -o Kmeans.o Kmeans.cpp
g++    -c -o cluster.o cluster.cpp
g++    -o clustering clustering.o data.o Kmeans.o cluster.o    <----
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have `Data::~Data` declaration in `data.h` and you do not have definition anywhere.

Just remove the declaration from header or add empty definition it it's a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

The error doesn't seem to be in your makefile, but in your CPP file. Try to compile it by hand and then use the makefile to automate it.

It could be that you've forgotten to write the definition of `Data::~Data()` in `data.cpp`

Sample MAKEFILE should be something like this:

```
#list of pseudo variables here

executable: object1.o object2.o object3.o
         ld -r object1.o object2.o object3.o -o executable

object1.o : object1.cpp
         $(CC) object.cpp -o object1.o

object2.o : object2.cpp
         $(CC) object2.cpp -o object2.o

object3.o : object3.cpp
         $(CC) object3.cpp -o object3.o
```

Comment: I can compile each file without problems but in the last part it fails:  

g++    -c -o clustering.o clustering.cpp
g++    -c -o data.o data.cpp
g++    -c -o Kmeans.o Kmeans.cpp
g++    -c -o cluster.o cluster.cpp
g++ -g -v  -o clustering clustering.o data.o Kmeans.o cluster.o

Comment: @Alex, why use $(CC) to link when you gotta use ld?